# using sendBroadcast in a system app

Tags: android

I'm having trouble sending a `Broadcast` from an app which is be loaded in a custom rom as a system app (Using `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in the `Manifest`).

The problem I'm getting is when trying to perform a simple sendBroadcast:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(intent.getExtras().getString(BUNDLE_ACTION_TO_REPLY_ON));
newIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_FILE_URI, bitmapFile.getAbsolutePath());
newIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_REPLY_WIDTH, width);
newIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_REPLY_HEIGHT, height);
newIntent.putExtra(BUNDLE_REPLY_EXTRA, extra);
context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

I'm getting this warning in Logcat:

`Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user`

This is being pumped out by [`ContextImpl.java`](http://mirror.yongbok.net/linux/android/repository/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) in the `warnIfCallingFromSystemProcess()` process.

Does anybody know why (and if I need to "fix" it)?

Comment: Can you show where you initialize context?

Comment: it's passed in as part of Broadcast Receiver (`public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)`)

Comment: This BroadcastReceiver is your system app?

Comment: There is a BroadcastReceiver in the app yup :)

Comment: Unfortunately the project has moved down my priority list so I didn't get a chance to try out @sMiLo s answer which looks like a good bet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use below function instead of `sendBroadcast(Intent intent)`.

```
void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user)
```

for example:

```
context.sendBroadcastAsUser(newIntent, new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT));
```

Comment: This can't be used by not pre-installed applications, read here : [link](http://goo.gl/J1GIXq)

Comment: @Mat : Yes. it's for system app only.

Comment: What is the `UserHandle.USER_CURRENT` parameter?

Comment: @AmitaiFensterheim : USER_CURRENT is a user handle to indicate all users on the device. Read this sources. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/UserHandle.java

Comment: `Process.myUserHandle()` instead of `new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT)` did the job for me

Comment: You don't need a new UserHandle object, just use `UserHandle.CURRENT`.