# Android System log when cellular data is on and off

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I want to know the meaning of following logs:

> 05-14 23:30:33.027  4271  7083 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the
>   system process without a qualified user:
>   android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:877
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:421
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MPhoneStateListener.onDataServiceChanged:470
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MPhoneStateListener.startDataOutOfService:457
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MSimPhoneStateListener.onServiceStateChanged:103
>
> 05-14 23:30:33.102  4271  7083 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the
>   system process without a qualified user:
>   android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:877
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:421
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MPhoneStateListener.onDataServiceChanged:470
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MPhoneStateListener.stopDataOutOfService:461
>   com.motorola.bach.modemstats.MSimPhoneStateListener.onServiceStateChanged:106

Are these logs about mobile cellular services start and stop? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850553/9025311

Answer (score 0):

Answering half part:
**ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:**
This warning comes when some system process is using methods like sendBroadcast, startActivity etc. To avoid this system process need to use methods with user handle,
like startActivityAsUser, sendBroadcastAsUser.

Rationality behind this using AsUser variant method allows to have user specific restrictions.

These warning are harmless as of now.

For logs from motorola, not sure regarding them. One way to check them is trying airplane mode on off or data on off and see if they are coming.